# Trouble with getting a mov file to appear in HTML and js

Tags: javascript, html, video, filepath, innerhtml

Right now, I'm trying to change the content of a webpage using javascript `querySelector` on a premade 'div' and set the `innerHTML` to the stuff I want it to be. So far, I've been successful in changing the content, however, I'm trying to get a .mov video file to show up with the code below, and it's throwing me an error in the terminal saying `ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine` Is there any way I can get the video to show up?

The mov file is in the exact same folder as the javascript file (both are in static/website), however when I tried to do `src="logo.mov"` it showed up in the console as not found.

**Here's the js I'm using to change the HTML:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('html').style.background = 'black';
    document.querySelector('#enter').innerHTML = `
        <video controls="controls" width="800"
            name="Video Name" src="static/website/logo.mov"></video>
    `
});
```

Comment: **(1)** _"...the javascript file"_ so you have some `.js` file involved? Make sure the `.html` and video file are in the same place then use `src="logo.mov"` **(2)** Make sure the MOV file format is supported by the playing browser. Does the file play if you open it directly in a new tab (_is supported_) or does it auto-download to hard drive (_not supported_)? **(3)** If all else fails, try converting MOV into MP4 and then test that new file.

Comment: @VC.One Ah okay, it seems as if my browser doesn't support MOV, I'm going to convert it and it should work

Comment: You can try [**Zamzar** or **Free-Convert**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=converting+mov+to+mp4+online) as a quick test to see if going to MP4 really fixes it